# SynchronizedObservableCollection: a thread-safe ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, thread-safety, collections

After reading many people talk about the need for a `SynchronizedObservableCollection` and their implementations I decided to roll my own. I wanted to add a `AddRange`, `RemoveRange`, and a way to `Replace` the entire contents without detaching event listeners.

This is supposed to be a thread-safe collection that produces change events.

- Did I succeed?
- Or have I made any fatal mistake?

```
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="SynchronizedCollection&lt;T&gt;"/> that implements features of <see cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;"/>
/// with the ability to gracefully add, remove, and replace all items.
/// </summary>
public class SynchronizedObservableCollection<T> : SynchronizedCollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    internal readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs CountPropertyChanged = new(nameof(Count));
    internal readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs IndexerPropertyChanged = new("Item[]");
    internal readonly NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ResetCollectionChanged = new(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;.CollectionChanged"/>
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;.CollectionChanged"/>
    protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public SynchronizedObservableCollection()
    { }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public SynchronizedObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public SynchronizedObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) { }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;.CollectionChanged"/>
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler? INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add => PropertyChanged += value;
        remove => PropertyChanged -= value;
    }

    private void OnCountPropertyChanged() => OnPropertyChanged(CountPropertyChanged);

    private void OnIndexerPropertyChanged() => OnPropertyChanged(IndexerPropertyChanged);

    private void OnCollectionReset() => OnCollectionChanged(ResetCollectionChanged);

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;.CollectionChanged"/>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ObservableCollection&lt;T&gt;.CollectionChanged"/>
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="Collection{T}.Add"/>
    public new void Add(T value)
    {
        base.Add(value);

        OnCountPropertyChanged();
        OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, value));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="Collection{T}.Remove"/>
    public new bool Remove(T value)
    {
        OnCountPropertyChanged();
        OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, value));

        return base.Remove(value);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="Collection{T}.Clear"/>
    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();

        OnCollectionReset();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="List{T}.AddRange"/>
    public virtual void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        bool updated = false;

        foreach (var item in range)
        {
            base.Add(item);
            updated = true;
        }

        if (updated)
        {
            OnCountPropertyChanged();
            OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, range));
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="List{T}.RemoveRange"/>
    public virtual bool RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        bool removed = false;
        foreach (T item in collection)
            removed |= base.Remove(item);

        if (removed)
        {
            OnCountPropertyChanged();
            OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, collection));
        }

        return removed;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows you to assign a new collection to this object without all the change listeners being destroyed!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range">The new contents of the collection.</param>
    public virtual void Replace(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        var newRange = range.ToList();
        if (newRange.Count == 0)
        {
            base.Clear();
            OnCollectionReset();

            return;
        }

        if (newRange.SequenceEqual(Items))
            return;

        base.Clear();
        OnCollectionReset();

        AddRange(newRange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what's the point of the `updated` and `removed` variables inside the `AddRange` and `RemoveRange` respectively?

Comment: Those are both flags that control if the property changed events will fire.

Comment: In case of `updated` it is used to check whether the `IEnumerable` parameter has at least one element in it or not. IMHO the `if(updated)` could be safely replaced with `if(range.Any())`.

Comment: I didn't do that to avoid multiple enumeration. Maybe that's a premature optimization.

Comment: `Any` is implemented in a pretty smart way. [First](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/adfae48391d47338d620c970d64a4bdec64fa7f8/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L95) it checks whether it is an `ICollection{<TSource>}` to use `Count` property or `IIListProvider` to use `GetCount` method. [Second](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L10) it uses an `IEnumerator<TSource>` to call the MoveNext()` and return its result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `Replace` has a race condition. Imagine the following situation:

- `thread 1` is calling the `Replace` with an empty array
- `thread 2` is calling the `Replace` with a `range` which sequentially equivalent with `Items`.

## Scenario #1

1. It might happen that `thread2` passed the `newRange.SequenceEqual(Items)` condition
2. then `thread1` clears the collection `base.Clear()`.
3. `thread2` returns when the collection is empty.

## Scenario #2

1. It might happen that `thread1` clears the collection `base.Clear()`.
2. then `thread2` do not pass the `newRange.SequenceEqual(Items)` condition
3. so `thread2` clears (the already emptied) collection (again)
4. and finally `thread2` adds back all the items

---

So, depending on the execution order either you clear the collection or recreate the collection.

Comment: Thanks! I was largely relying on the locking behavior of `base` but what you are showing is that I also need to implement more `lock (SyncRoot)` around my custom methods to make them more thread safe. The trouble is that I can't wrap the whole thing in a lock because nested locks would dead-lock...

Comment: @HackSlash Exactly, the `SynchronizedCollection` works fine for primitive (atomic) operations. But whenever you start to combine multiple ones or implement "complex" logic like your `Replace` it fails. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655150/) you can read more about this topic.